# Angular.js ui-sref is not creating hyperlink

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I know this question might be stupid,but after searching through all over the stackoverflow and other blogs,and video tutorials,I have no other choice left than to ask this on stackoverflow.
I have been learning Angular.js through online tutorials.

> I have 2 files.
>    index.html and app.js

Here is some snaps of my code.

> States Configuration Part inside app.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']).config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: '/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')}]);
```

> Inline templates inside index.html (1-home.html , 2-posts.html)

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
  <!--home.html part-->
</script>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <!--posts.html part-->
</script>
```

inside home.html I have a hyperlink on Comments.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
    ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
  {{post.upvotes}}
  <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
      {{post.title}}
    </a>
    <span ng-hide="post.link">
      {{post.title}}
    </span>
    <span>
      <a ui-sref="/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Now when I run this WebApp on my localhost it is showing this rendered html of my Comment hyperlink,but it is not providing me any navigation(Hyperlink is not working).

```
<span>
     <a ui-sref="/posts/0">Comments</a>
</span>
```

Now,I have two questions:

1. What went wrong with ui-sref part.When I use href instead of ui-sref then it is working perfectly fine.Why is this happening?
2. I have been using inline templates for home.html and posts.html,but if I make them into separate files then my entire app gets broken.Why?

Any help would be appreciative.

Comment: Did you check your browser dev console?Any errors logged when using templates as separate files?

Comment: It is showing this: http://localhost/home.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)The way you have used `ui-sref` is what is causing it to break.Try this in your application,

```
<a ui-sref="posts({ id: $index })">Comments</a>
```

2)Assuming your new template files are as same level as your index.html and app.js you need not mention as `templateUrl: '/posts.html'`,just use `templateUrl: 'posts.html'`.

Comment: for question no 1 or 2?

Comment: for question no: 2,It is showing this: localhost/home.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please check for the second answer.

Comment: Question 2 is a routing issue. Are you putting your separated .html files in the same parent folder as your index.html?

Comment: Your solution for 2nd question worked magically.Seriously it was a silly mistake.Thank you btw.

Comment: @DanKeiger yes,I am putting those files in same parent folder.